# Saving the result of Select statement from SqlDataReader to list at once

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, select

As the questions says, I'm trying to save the result of a select statement from a `SqlDataReader` to a list at once, rather than one by one giving the column name.

Before that I've tried using `reader.read()` and then giving the column name one by one and saving the data something like this,

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    label.text = (string) reader["myColumn"];
    //..... and so on repeating for all the columns in the DB.
}
```

Yet I've tried using `IDataRecord` to put all the row values in the list but it gives me NULL.

```
if (reader.HasRows)
{
    List<string> list = (from IDataRecord r in reader
                         select (string)r["FieldName"]).ToList();
}
```

But this returns a NULL. Anyone can redirect me to proper piece of information will highly be regarded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SqlDataReader` requires you to read and move the pointer one row by one row. If you want to get all the data at once, you could use `SqlDataAdapter` and `DataTable`.

Comment: Thank you so much. Tried the Data Adapter and got what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("connection string");
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select top 10 documentid from document order by 1 desc", con);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();             

            List<string> docids = (from IDataRecord r in dr select (string)r["documentid"]).ToList<string>();
            con.Close();
```